# Start an angular 4 application - What editor?

Tags: .net, angular, web, architecture

I am learning angular 4 and I wondered to start a new project what editor would be advisable to use, and in terms of architecture?

- Use visual studio code and develop the web app completely separated from the server side?
- Use the visual studio and embedded angular in a MVC or Api app?
- Build an Api in visual studio in a separate project?

Comment: This Q is best suited for [a different Stack forum](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I doubt there is one "best" answer. My own project is divided into two projects. A front-end Angular project, and a back-end PHP project. They are both handled by PhpStorm IDE though.

Answer (score 1):

I have develop both frontend and backend with Visual studio code. I use this template https://github.com/damienbod/AngularWebpackVisualStudio/blob/master/README.md

And my project looks like this https://github.com/JanneHarju/MultiSourcePlayList
 And I only use Visual Studio Code in my MacBook.

But someone might say that you should separate them at least into separate folders. And that is possible with this template you just need to modify little bit webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 main options at the moment.

**Dotnet angular boilerplate from MS**

Basically it's Angular 4 project inside ASP.NET Core project. It follows the same folder structure as any ASP.NET Core project + it have ClientApp folder where you app lives. Everything built with Webpack and you have 2 configs: vendor and client.

In this case you develop in VS 2017. I don't see any other options here.

**Angular CLI project + ASP.NET Core Web API**

This is my favorite setup. You have 2 completely separate project and you can build backend and frontend in your favorite IDEs. My preferable for Web UI development is WebStorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ . It's paid one , but this price is nothing for the functionality.

**Cons/pros/thoughts**

From the backend point there's no difference.

From deployment point it's easier to deploy single project. In case of ASP.NET Core it's almost 1-click publish to Azure. Build is also easier to setup with a single project.

From configuration point it's easier to configure Angular CLI. It encapsulates webpack.config file and provides you with a very convenient way of managing things like what should go into assets, which CSS preproc to use, etc.

From development environment point with the first setup you bound to Windows 10. I'm a Mac user even though I have both Windows and MacOS on my mac because I develop in both environments; and I can tell that VS for Mac is not ready for solid development yet.

So the choice is yours! :) But my belief is that you can build cool app with any of these setups. It's the same code at the end ;)